# SoapCore WCF C# program using XmlSerializer doesn't create the WSDL with async methods with CancellationToken

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, cancellation-token, soapcore

I have an issue in async WCF service using SoapCore in .Net 6 using a cancellation token and XmlSerializer serializer.

The detailed WCF application is as follows:

- WCF service in C# .Net Core 6 using `SoapCore` NuGet package using `SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer` serializer
- I created an async method that has the `[OperationContract]` attribute with a `CancellationToken` parameter
- I try to get the WSDL using the URL `https://localhost:7026/Services.svc?WSDL` and it fails because of the `CancellationToken` with the exception `ArgumentException: .NET type CancellationToken cannot be resolved into XML schema type` (`CancellationToken` has namespace starting with `System` (`System.Threading.CancellationToken`), is a structure (value type), and is categorized by `SoapCore` code as very similar to `bool`, `int`, `long`, ... and tries to generate an XML for it and it fails)
- I tried adding the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute to the parameter `CancellationToken` of the method having the `[OperationContract]` attribute and it doesn't work
- `[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]` cannot be added to parameters of methods

**Note:** This works with `SoapCore` with `SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer` serializer, but the generated WSDL is bigger enumerating many basic types that I don't use and I want to use `SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer` if possible.

**Program.cs** code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using SoapCore;

namespace TestSoapCore;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddSoapCore();
        builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<MyService>();
        builder.Services.AddMvc();

        var app = builder.Build();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<MyService>(
                "/Services.svc",
                new SoapEncoderOptions(),
                SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer
                // This works with SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer but I prefer SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer if possible
            );
        });
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

**Contract.cs** code:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace TestSoapCore;

[DataContract]
public class Contract {
    [DataMember]
    public string? TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**MyService.cs** code:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace TestSoapCore;

[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public async Task<string> Test(
        Contract contract,
        // [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)] cannot be added to parameters
        [XmlIgnore] // This doesn't work
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        return contract?.TestProperty + "2";
    }
}
```

Full exception while getting the WSDL at `https://localhost:7026/Services.svc?WSDL` when `SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer` serializer is used:
[image: Exception while getting the WSDL]

How the WSDL works with `SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer` serializer without any `CancellationToken` (but I want the `CancellationToken` for async methods, it is better to have it):
[image: WSDL with SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer that is not bloated but without CancellationToken]

How the WSDL is bloated and has many basic types I don't use when `SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer` serializer is used (that's why I still prefer `SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer` if possible):

- Part 1:
  [image: WSDL with SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer part 1]
- Part 2:
  [image: WSDL with SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer part 2]
- Part 3:
  [image: WSDL with SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer part 3]
- Part 4:
  [image: WSDL with SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer part 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `CancellationToken` is not working very well with WCF using SoapCore (`SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer` serializer doesn't generate the WSDL because of `CancellationToken` and `SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer` serializer puts the `CancellationToken` as an object that needs to be sent with many properties and their types) I ended up removing the `CancellationToken` entirely and I used the `SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer` to have less data (WSDL not bloated with all the unused types, many pages of useless data).

PS: This is how the `CancellationToken` looks with SoapCore and `SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer` serializer (not very nice..):
[image: CancellationToken in WSDL]

Answer (score 1):

Like [Aleksander Ch response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74483400), but mixed with the example of [official page](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore#how-to-get-custom-http-header-in-soapcore-service)

Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    public void SetCancellationToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    [OperationContract]
    public Task<int> CheckStatus();
}
```

Service (Very important ThreadLocal variable)

```
public sealed class Service : IService
{
    private readonly ThreadLocal<CancellationToken> _threadCancellationToken = new();

    Task<int> ILectoService.CheckStatus()
    {
        if (_threadCancellationToken.IsValueCreated)
            _threadCancellationToken.Value.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ........
    }

    void ILectoService.SetCancellationToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _threadCancellationToken.Value = cancellationToken;
    }
}
```

ServiceOperationTuner

```
internal sealed class ServiceOperationTuner : IServiceOperationTuner
{
    public void Tune(HttpContext httpContext, object serviceInstance, SoapCore.ServiceModel.OperationDescription operation)
    {
        if (serviceInstance is IService service)
        {
            service.SetCancellationToken(httpContext.RequestAborted);
        }
    }
}
```

Add service operation tuner in Program

```
builder.Services.AddSoapServiceOperationTuner(new ServiceOperationTuner());
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to get SoapCore working with cancellation token there is another approach. SoapCore allows us to define ServiceOperationTuner which can read the cancellationToken from HttpContext and than assign it to service. The example bellow explains the idea of sollution

Define service operation tuner

```
public class ServiceOperationTuner : IServiceOperationTuner
{
    public void Tune(HttpContext httpContext, object serviceInstance, OperationDescription operation)
    {
        if (serviceInstance != null && serviceInstance is MyService)
        {
            MyService service = serviceInstance as MyService;
            service.SetCancellationToken(httpContext.RequestAborted);
        }
    }
}
```

Add service operation tuner in Program

```
builder.Services.AddSoapServiceOperationTuner(new ServiceOperationTuner());
```

Modify MyService in order to get cancellationToken

```
public class MyService
{
    
    CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
        
    public void SetCancellationToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    }
```